# bad_alloc while initializing and filling a vector?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, vector

While trying to generate a vector of random numbers I stumble across a std::bad_alloc error. Here's my code:

```
#include "search.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int _size = 100;

std::vector<int> GetSortedVector(int size){
    //init vector
    std::vector<int> v(size);
    //fill with random numbers
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v.push_back( std::rand()%(2*size) );
    //return the setup vector
    return v;
}

//triggered automatically
TEST(BinarySearch, NonUniqueSorted){
    std::vector<int> v = GetSortedVector(_size);//nothing moves farther than this line
}
```

**P.S.:** I do use `generate()` by now, but am still curious why it failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`v.push_back` increases the size, so `i<v.size()` is never `false`.

Since your vector is already `size` in length, you need to fill it with

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i < v.size(); i++)
    v[i] = std::rand()%(2*size);
```

or use `reserve` instead:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(size);
```

keep the `push_back` and check against `size`. I won't suggest `std::generate` because you said you're already doing it like that.

Comment: In case of reserving the for loop must be modified to check against the capacity not size.

Comment: I don't think checking against `capacity` would be a good idea, since as far as I know `reserve` is *allowed* to overallocate (even if maybe practically not doing it). Rather just check against `size` (the function argument).

Comment: But generate works great and is more clear from maintenance point of view. Why is it bad?

Comment: @den-javamaniac Huh? Who said `generate` was bad? It is indeed the best solution to your problem, it's just totally unrelated to your actual question, which was correctly answered by this answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau, misunderstood the statement regarding generate, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom into the following part:

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v.push_back( std::rand()%(2*size) );
```

Every time you call `push_back()`, vector's size is increased by 1. Therefore, `i < v.size()` will never evaluate to false and your loop will go on until you run out of memory. One of the possible ways to fix it is to capture `size()` once, for example:

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i=0, s = v.size(); i < s; i++)
        v.push_back( std::rand()%(2*size) );
```

Comment: You should mention that your latter suggestion increases the vector **without** modifying the original contents.

Comment: I doubt the OP actually wants a hundred zeros followed by a hundred pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Right. The question was about bad_alloc, and not how to update elements in place. Though all of your suggestions are valid :)

Comment: Looks like the OP is smart and has tests in place that will catch if the leading zeroes are not desired.